# Compare percentage variations between variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have accounting DataFrame and want to check some facts but the main problem is that they are not "playing" on the same league.

The DF is something like this:

```
    A      B      C      D      E   
x   1     1.5    1.1    0.8     1
y  100    120    90     115     102
z  1000   1100  1800    900    1000
```

I want to check their path between variables ABCDE , so result should be something like this:

```
           A      B      C      D      E  
    x(%)   0     50      10    -20     0

    y(%)   0     20     -10     15     2

    z(%)   0     10      80    -10     0
```

Or

```
               A      B      C      D      E  
    x(%)   100     150      110    80     0

    y(%)   100     120      90     115    102

    z(%)   100     110      180    90    100
```

The idea I have is :

```
df2 = df
df2.iloc[0]= ( (df2.iloc[0] * 100 ) / df2["A"].iloc[0] ) -100
df2.iloc[1]= ( (df2.iloc[1] * 100 ) / df2["A"].iloc[1] ) -100
df2.iloc[2]= ( (df2.iloc[2] * 100 ) / df2["A"].iloc[2] ) -100
# (-100 is for first example)
```

But, do you know a "non manual" way for this?

Data:

```
{'A': {'x': 1, 'y': 100, 'z': 1000},
 'B': {'x': 1.5, 'y': 120, 'z': 1100},
 'C': {'x': 1.1, 'y': 90, 'z': 1800},
 'D': {'x': 0.8, 'y': 115, 'z': 900},
 'E': {'x': 1, 'y': 102, 'z': 1000}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert "A" to a numpy column vector and use broadcasting:

```
df = (df / df["A"].to_numpy()[:, None] - 1) * 100
```

Output:

```
     A     B     C     D    E
x  0.0  50.0  10.0 -20.0  0.0
y  0.0  20.0 -10.0  15.0  2.0
z  0.0  10.0  80.0 -10.0  0.0
```